# How to fit UITableview with iPhone 5 screen size?

Tags: ios, uitableview, iphone-5

I have tried the solution from image in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678910/uitableviewcontroller-last-row-cut-off). However, it only works when the screen is first loaded, when the app goes back to that screen again from the screen's child, it goes back to cut off tableview.

After I NSLog the tableview height in viewWillAppear:

```
340.00 (tableview first loaded)
245.00 (tableview re-appeared)
```

Is there anything I miss?

I also tried to add

```
tableResult.autoresizingMask &= ~UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

and

```
tableResult.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;
```

but none of them works.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the height of the table to be flexible:

```
tableResult.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: nope it doesn't work.. I added the code tableResult.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; but doesn't work..

Comment: You should remove the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` since you want to the table view to grow with the height of the view.

Comment: i see.. But it doesn't give me any luck :(